# Show that $\lim \int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)dx = 0$,where $f_{n}(x)$ is (i) $\frac{nx (\log x)}{1+n^2x^2}$ . (ii) $\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Show that $\lim \int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)dx = 0$, where $f_{n}(x)$ is
(i) $\frac{nx (\log x)}{1+n^2x^2}$ and 
(ii) $\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$

Comment: i don't know how to prove . Help me.

Comment: For ii) see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679679/convergence-of-frac2nt1n2t2-in-c-0-1 . Now try to prove i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (i), you may rewrite $$f_n(x)=\dfrac{\log x}{\frac{1}{nx}+nx}$$ and then remark that $$\frac{1}{nx}+nx=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{nx}}-\sqrt{nx}\right)^2+2\geq2$$ Then for every nonnegative integer $n$, $|f_n(x)|\leq\frac12|\log x|$ and $\log$ is integrable over $[0,1]$.

On the other hand, $f_n(x)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Therefore you can use the **dominated convergence theorem** to get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\mathrm{d}x=0$$

For (ii), the same method still works.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: Note that the monotone convergence theorem works as well, since $(|f_n|)$ is a decreasing sequence of integrable functions.